# is there a way to connect to sanity.io database / datastore data from Metabase?

Tags: metabase, sanity

I just found out about Sanity.io and think it is really really cool. But as Im new to it I haven't found a way to connect Metabase ( data analytics ) to sanity's database. Is that even possible? My team is used to Metabase and would be nice if they could do some querys on the data being store in Sanity.io database or dataset.

Thanks, all your help is appreciated

Technologies:
-- Sanity.io
-- Metabase.com

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. It might help if you used an example to describe exactly what sort of problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanxs in your interest in helping 
Content Lake is Sanity.Io ‘database’ where all data is stored. Is there a way to connect to it like a database service ( domain:port and credentials ) in order to do queries for statistics?

Metabase is good for making charts and dashboards from data.

My end aim is to be able to easily query and analyzed the data store in sanity.

If using metabase is not an option, could you suggest me other options. Thx

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLAic.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hf270.jpg
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXoly.jpg

Answer (score 0):

So as for now I understand that it will not be possible to do a direct connection. That probably the best approach is to do ETL from sanity to a SQL database and connect that database to Metabase